# Way to compare index of 2 lists?

Tags: python-3.6

Hi guys how do I compare index of 2 lists (by linking them together)

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

For exammple, let's say I want to print a value from `b` after inputing a value from `a` into another variable, how do I go about doing that where output generated is for examples : a and 1 
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match the variables:

```
>>> data = dict(zip(b,a))
>>> data['a']
1
>>> for k,v in data.items():
...     print k,v
```

Maybe you are looking for [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), in that case you should have your data defined immediately instead of two arrays:

```
data = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Where you can still get two distinct arrays:

```
>>> data.keys()
['a','c','b','d']

>>> data.values()
[1,3,2,4]
```

**Edit:**

Since you are also looking a way to start with the value input and keeping the arrays:

```
y=[1,2,3,4]
x=['a','b','c','d']

value = int(input("Enter a value:"))

try:
    y_index = y.index(value)
    print(x[y.index(value)])
except Exception as e:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: `
values=int(input("Enter a value:"))

y=[1,2,3,4]

x=['a','b','c','d']

i=y.index

if values in y:

    print("The value and letter is {} and {}".format(y,x));

else:

    print("Error") `

does this work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. What is your expected input?

Comment: like basically check if value inputted is in y and if its in ,print the value together with the corresponding variable by index from x and if it isnt print an error messae

Comment: added the value input version to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
for index in range(0,len(a)):
    print(a[index],b[index]);
```

Comment: I am assuming you just want to print the contents of the two lists and that the size of the two lists is equal.

Comment: oh sorry misunderstood your question. The thing you are trying to do is easily achievable if you will be using a dictionary in python